Trying to clear only part of the terminal screen so my timer could work
I've been trying to make a timer in Python as a project, and I want the terminal to display the exact, current time (to the nearest second) AS WELL as allowing user input while displaying it.
import os
import time
import datetime
import asyncio

i = 1
timermade = False

async def printtime():
    global today
    today = datetime.date.today()
    timei = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H : %M : %S")
    print(f"The date now is {today}\n")
    print(f"The time now is {timei}")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('clear')
    await printtime()

def maketimer():
    print("\nSet a predefined timer:")
    y = input("Set year (leave blank if unneeded)")
    m = input("Set month (leave blank if unneeded)")
    d = input("Set day (leave blank if unneeded)")
    h = input("Set hour (leave blank if unneeded)")
    mt = input("Set minute (leave blank if unneeded)")
    s = input("Set second (leave 0 if unneeded)")
    global timer
    timer = datetime.datetime(y, m, d, h, mt, s)
    if (timer <= datetime.datetime(0,0,0,0,0,0)):
        print("Error: Timer cannot be negative numbers/zero")
        maketimer()
    else:
        print(timer)
        while (timer <= datetime.datetime(0,0,0,0,0,0)):
            os.system('clear')
            printtime()
            print("Time remaining:")
            print(timer)


while timermade == False:
    asyncio.run(printtime())

maketimer()


What is the problem with what you have now?

the clock works.  what input do you want the user to do ?   if you are seeking input, then surely tkinter would be nicer ?

So you want to create two threads : One getting input from the user, and the other one displaying a timer. Correct?
